# How to change font in RusselResume Overleaf

Tags: fonts, templates, bold, cv

I am trying to use the RusselResume template to write my resume on Overleaf, but I would like to change the font.

Right now this is what was already written:

```
\newcommand*{\headerfont}{\roboto}
\newcommand*{\headerfontlight}{\robotolight}
\newcommand*{\footerfont}{\sourcesanspro}
\newcommand*{\bodyfont}{\sourcesanspro}
```

I have tried:

```
\newcommand*{\headerfont}{\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\headerfontlight}{\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\footerfont}{\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\bodyfont}{\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\bodyfontlight}{\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont}
```

instead, which gave me the font I wanted. However, none of the section headers were in bold letters anymore. I have tried adding

```
\fontseries{ub}
```

to those lines above, but that did nothing. I would like a different font, but also want to keep the thickness of the letters in the original font. How do I do this?

Comment: ptm accesses a very old times setup but you would want `\fontseries{b}` there is no ultra-bold

Comment: I don't have an Overleaf account, but if the template is the one available [here](https://github.com/themagicalmammal/Resume), it uses fontspec and thus xelatex or lualatex. It would probably work with commands like `\renewcommand*{\bodyfont}{\fontspec{TeX Gyre Termes}}` and so on for the others. (Change "TeX Gyre Termes" to whatever system font you want, e.g., "Times New Roman") I'd use `\renewcommand*` at the end of the preamble, and not change the original `\newcommand*`s in the document class file; document classes should not be edited by end users if you can avoid it.